# MySQLi Prepare Statement and OOP PHP Query Returns 0 Row

Tags: php, php-5.6

Trying to get data from MySQLi using PHP OOP apporoach I am getting `No rows` while  I am sure I have match row in the database

I have a class called `db` stored in a file as `db.inc.php` and it is like

```
<?PHP
class db {
    private $DBSERVER;
    private $DBUSERNAME;
    private $DBPASSWORD;
    private $DBNAME;

    protected function connect(){
      $this->DBSERVER   = "localhost"; 
      $this->DBUSERNAME = "root"; 
      $this->DBPASSWORD = ""; 
      $this->DBNAME     = "maator"; 

      $conn = new mysqli($this->DBSERVER, $this->DBUSERNAME, $this->DBPASSWORD, $this->DBNAME);
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      }     
      return $conn;
    }
}
?>
```

I have an extended class called `SetData` in `SetData.inc.php` which like

```
<?PHP
include_once('db.inc.php'); 
class SetData extends db {
    private $page;
    private $region;
    private $conn;

    function __construct() {
       $this->conn = new db();
    }

   public function SetBox($vpage, $vregion){
        $this->page     = $vpage;
        $this->region = $vregion;
        $stmt = $this->conn->connect()->prepare("SELECT `title`,`description` FROM html WHERE `page` = ? AND `region` = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $this->page, $this->region);    
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
       if($stmt->num_rows === 0) exit('No rows');
        $stmt->bind_result($titlerow,$descriptionrow);
        $stmt->fetch();
            $title = $titlerow;
            $description = $descriptionrow;
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
?>
```

and finally in front page I have

```
<?PHP
$page = 'game';
$region = 'ASIA';
include '../inc/SetData.inc.php';
$cls = new SetData();
$cls->SetBox($page, $region);
```

Comment: Thanks @AbraCadaver, after doing this I am getting this error now `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method db::prepare()`

Comment: `$cls->SetMetas($page, $region);` should possibly call a method which exists. and somehow, a `return` statement might be nice to have; else the values will be gone, when the object is being destructed.

Comment: Hi Martin there was a typo on posted coed , sorry about that I fix it now and the actual method name is `$cls->SetBox($page, $region);`

Comment: @MonaCoder try `NetBeans`, `Eclipse` or `VS.Code` in combination with `xdebug` ...this might make life as a PHP skripter a whole lot easier, because then there are break-points & watches available. you'd just need a localhost web-server for that... what your script does, is setting two local variables in a public method of a class, which gets destructed after `$stmt->close()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `dbconnect()` is, you need to call your `connect()` method here:

```
//$this->conn = new dbconnect(); // NO!

$this->conn = $this->connect();
```

Also, you shouldn't call `connect()` here, you already have a connection in `$conn`:

```
//$stmt = $this->conn->connect()->prepare("SELECT `title`,`description` FROM html WHERE `page` = ? AND `region` = ?"); // NO!

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT `title`,`description` FROM html WHERE `page` = ? AND `region` = ?");
```

Then, what do you want to do with `$title` and `description`?  Maybe return them?

```
    $stmt->bind_result($titlerow, $descriptionrow);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();

    return array('title' => $titlerow, 'description' => $descriptionrow);
```

Then call `SetBox()` and display:

```
$result = $cls->SetBox($page, $region);
echo $result['title'];
```

Or set properties:

```
    $stmt->bind_result($titlerow, $descriptionrow);
    $stmt->fetch();

    $this->title = $titlerow;
    $this->description = $descriptionrow;

    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
```

Then call `SetBox()` and display:

```
$cls->SetBox($page, $region);
echo $cls->title;
```